# Flurry integration with iOS app results in link errors

Tags: ios, flurry, flurry-analytics

I am trying to integrate Flurry with my iOS app.
I have create a simple single page app.
downloaded viPhone 7.1.1
added flurry.h, flurrywatch.h & libFlurry_7.1.1.a to my project
added security.framework & systemconfiguration.framework libraries as listed in the readme.

Then added [Flurry startSession:key];
Now when I compile, I get loads of link error as listed below, pls guid me what I am missing.

link error:

```
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(CrashReporter.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(CrashReporter.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashSignalHandler.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashSignalHandler.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashFrameWalker.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashFrameWalker.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashLogWriter.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashLogWriter.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsync.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsync.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashLogWriterEncoding.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashLogWriterEncoding.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReportSystemInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReportSystemInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncSignalInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncSignalInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncImageList.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncImageList.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashSysctl.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashSysctl.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncThread_current-9289CCF9E0DE787E.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncThread_current-9289CCF9E0DE787E.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporterNSError.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporterNSError.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncMachOImage.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncMachOImage.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncMObject.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncMObject.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncObjCSection.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncObjCSection.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncSymbolication.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncSymbolication.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncMachOString.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncMachOString.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashMachExceptionServer.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashMachExceptionServer.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashFrameStackUnwind.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashFrameStackUnwind.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncThread.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncThread.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncThread_x86.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncThread_x86.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashFrameCompactUnwind.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashFrameCompactUnwind.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncCompactUnwindEncoding.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncCompactUnwindEncoding.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfEncoding.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfEncoding.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfPrimitives.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfPrimitives.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfFDE.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfFDE.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfCIE.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfCIE.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfCFAStateEvaluation.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfCFAStateEvaluation.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfExpression.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfExpression.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(dwarf_opstream.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(dwarf_opstream.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfCFAState.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncDwarfCFAState.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashFrameDWARFUnwind.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashFrameDWARFUnwind.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashProcessInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashProcessInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashHostInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashHostInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashMachExceptionPort.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashMachExceptionPort.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashMachExceptionPortSet.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashMachExceptionPortSet.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncMachExceptionInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashAsyncMachExceptionInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporterConfig.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporter.o)
    /Users/.../Documents/Projects/XCode_Repository/TestingAnalytics2/TestingAnalytics2/libFlurry_7.1.1.a(PLCrashReporterConfig.o)
ld: 76 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I've had the same problem when upgrading to 7.1.1 I'm pretty sure this is a n issue on their end. In the meantime downgrading to 7.1.0 solves the problem. Are you still using Xcode 6.4 ? I haven't upgraded to Xcode 7 yet and I'm wondering if this is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official advice to resolve this issue could be found at [*Get Started with Flurry Analytics for iOS*](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/ios/#integrate-the-sdk-with-your-app) docs:

> **Important**
>
> If you are using Xcode 7, you can use the latest version of
>   the Flurry SDK (7.1.1). Otherwise, please use the SDK 7.1.0. You can
>   acquire Flurry SDK 7.1.0 from the Cocoapods following the instructions
>   provided below. For direct integration the library files are available
>   from https://github.com/flurry/Flurry-iOS-SDK/tree/7.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Go through the steps given in the this official link:

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/publisher/code/ios/

Make sure you follow every step given in the above link. Also give your attention for special 'Note' & 'Important' section.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to the Flurry support and they suggested me to upgrade Xcode to latest version, that solved the issue.

Thanks
Shil